# Entity Framework 4.3 accessing abstract Class collection throws ArgumentNull Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity framework 4.3 code first to persist a domain model. The domain model consists of abstract and concrete classes. I see a ArgumentNullException thrown when a concrete class returned by the entity framework first tries to access a collection of objects in the base class.

For example a domain model consists of the abstract classes

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attibute> attributes { get; set; }

    public string DoSomething()
    {
        return "I'm all fooey";
    }
}

public abstract class Attibute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

I then have derived classes like

```
public class BadFoo : Foo
{
    public List<BadAttribute> BadAttribs()
    {
        return base.attributes.OfType<BadAttribute>().ToList<BadAttribute>();
    }

    public void BeBad()
    {
        foreach (var a in BadAttribs())
            Console.WriteLine(Name + ": Being bad => " + a.DoingBad());
    }
}

public class GoodFoo : Foo
{
    public List<GoodAttribute> GoodAttribs()
    {
        return base.attributes.OfType<GoodAttribute>().ToList<GoodAttribute>();
    }

    public void BeGood()
    {
       foreach (var a in GoodAttribs())
            Console.WriteLine(Name + ": Being good => " + a.DoingGood());
    }
}


public class BadAttribute : Attibute
{
    public string DoingBad()
    {
        return Name + " : Start being bad";
    }
}

public class GoodAttribute : Attibute
{
    public string DoingGood()
    {
        return Name + " : Start being Good";
    }
}

public class AppearenceAttribute : Attibute
{
    public string Doing()
    {
        return Name + " : defining ones appearance";
    }
}
```

I then set up my db context as follows:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attibute> Attributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class EFDbContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EFDbContext> 
{
    protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
    {
        List<Attibute> attribs = new List<Attibute>
            {
                new BadAttribute { Name = "Gluttony" },
                new BadAttribute { Name = "Greed" },
                new GoodAttribute { Name = "Honesty" },
                new GoodAttribute { Name = "Humility" },
                new AppearenceAttribute { Name = "Colour" }
            };
        attribs.ForEach(a => context.Attributes.Add(a));
        context.SaveChanges();

        BadFoo badOne = new BadFoo { Name = "badOne", attributes = new List<Attibute>)};

        context.Attributes.OfType<BadAttribute>().ToList().ForEach(a => badOne.attributes.Add(a));
        context.Attributes.OfType<AppearenceAttribute>().ToList().ForEach(a => badOne.attributes.Add(a));

        context.Foos.Add(badOne);
        context.SaveChanges();

        GoodFoo goodOne = new GoodFoo { Name = "GoodOne", attributes = new List<Attibute>() };

        context.Attributes.OfType<GoodAttribute>().ToList().ForEach(a => goodOne.attributes.Add(a));
        context.Attributes.OfType<AppearenceAttribute>().ToList().ForEach(a => goodOne.attributes.Add(a));

        context.Foos.Add(goodOne);
        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

I then use my model as follows:

```
       Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(new EFDbContextInitializer());

        EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        var foos = context.Foos.OfType<BadFoo>().ToList();
        foreach (var f in foos)
            f.BeBad();

        var foos2 = context.Foos.OfType<GoodFoo>().ToList();
        foreach (var f in foos2)
            f.BeGood();

        Console.ReadKey();
```

The exception is thrown when a concrete class derived from Foo first tries to use the collection in Foo base class. In this case the first time an instance of BadFoo calls the BeBad() method.

I am not sure if it's because EF lazy loading the collection, the way C# deals with abstract/concrete classes or the domain model just sucks anyone care to explain/enlighten me as to the problem(s)?

As a side note if I replace the way the base attributes are accessed in the derived attribute classes BadFoo and GoodFoo to be properties which return a type filtered list of the base class collection property like :

```
public class GoodFoo : Foo
{
    public List<GoodAttribute> GoodAttribs()
    {
        return base.attributes.OfType<GoodAttribute>().ToList<GoodAttribute>();
    }
}
```

EF adds an _Id column to the table why is that?

Comment: Does replacing `base.attributes` with `this.attributes` fix anything?

Comment: No doesn't fix anything. If disable EF proxy creation, remove virtual from the navigation properties then replace the property on a derived type, say GoodFoo.GoodAttribs with a class method that access the attributes of the base class then I can get it to work. Not sure why the property accessor on derived type wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

EF code first builds db model metadata based on the configuration and context definition. You've set up EF to use abstract Foo and Attribute classes as entities. So it tries to use it.

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attibute> Attributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

It doesn't know anything about your descendand classes and doesn't know how to map them. It seems to me that you can't use abstract classes as entities, because it is doesn't make any sense.

In any case your Foo and Attibute classes are not abstract classes by the nature. They don't have any abstract methods. I recommend you to read more about abstract classes in C# or abstract keyword.